# Wordpress: Get all Terms for products that have a selected term_id

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying and failing to get all Term_Ids and Names for Terms that have:

A specific type (pa_height) and are used in products that also use a selected known term_taxonomy_id

Basically I need to search all products in the wp_term_relationships that have a specific term_id and then from this list of products find all products that have another term of type (pa_height) and finally grab a list of these pa_height terms to populate a second dropdown.

Current sql: tables and a rough outline of problem:

```
$querystr = "
    select *
    from wp_term_taxonomy
    join wp_term_relationships relation on relation.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
    left join (select * from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id = '23') prods on relation.object_id = prods.object_id
    left join (select * from wp_term_taxonomy where taxonomy = 'pa_height') heights on relation.term_taxonomy_id = heights.term_id
";
```

Tables:

wp_term_relationships:

object_id (Product_Id)
term_taxonomy_id (ID of the Term)
term_order (Not Applicable)

wp_term_taxonomy

term_taxonomy_id
term_id (Matches term_taxonomy_id from wp_term_relationships)
taxonomy (Contains type in this case pa_height etc.)

wp_terms
term_id matches term_id from 2 tables above
name
slug

I need to get the term_id, name from wp_terms for all products that have the term_id I am searching for.

I am searching for a single term id (pa_width) and need all products with this id, then I need to use this list of products to output a list of the terms they have only if the term is of type (pa_height) and finally link this to the wp_term table to get the name + id

Comment: What do you mean by "terms that have a specific type"? Terms do not have 'types" as far as I know.

Comment: In wp_taxonomy_id the term has a type, i.e taxonomy : pa_width.  Attribute i assume is the easiest way to explain it!

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, the SQL was pretty intense, and left join did not work

Now getting the attributes needed based on another attribute selected.

Posting here for future reference:

```
                select *
            from wp_term_taxonomy
            join wp_term_relationships relation on relation.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
            join (select * from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id = $width) prods on relation.object_id = prods.object_id
            join (select * from wp_term_taxonomy where taxonomy = 'pa_height') heights on relation.term_taxonomy_id = heights.term_id
            join wp_terms termies on termies.term_id = heights.term_id
            group by wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
            order by termies.name
```

Comment: I don't understand your `$width` variable, and you don't mention it anywhere in your question/answer